# How to use JSONSerialization.jsonObject with jagged array (json data) from php in SWIFT 3

Tags: ios, json, dictionary, swift3, nsjsonserialization

So I have a JSON data returning from a php file:

```
{"is_success":1,"message":"Has sync","data":[{"id":"7","customer_id":"007"}]}
```

And I have a swift code:

```
if var myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [NSDictionary]
{
            for jsonDict in myJSON
            {
                 var try: String = (jsonDict["customer_id"] as? String)!
            }
}
```

Apparently, it won't go inside the if statement because of the `[NSDictionary]`. I tried `[String: AnyObject]`, `[NSDictionary]`, and etc from other guides and it just won't work. Any suggestions to replace the `[NSDictionary]`? Thanks!

Comment: you are making array of dictionary `[NSDictionary]`... it should be dictionary `NSDictionary` .. in swift3 it should be `[String:Any]`

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 i tried [String:Any], it won't still get into that if statement

Comment: `if let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any] { print("true")}`  .. try this does it prints true

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Hey there, it still wont go inside the if statement :( I have put 'print 1' before executing that if statement, and 'print 2' inside that if, and it wont have no idea why. It just prints 'print 1'

Comment: thanks @EICaptainv2.0! It now works :D

Comment: ohhh... good .. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON response is type of `Dictionary` not `Array`.

```
if let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String : Any] {
    //For getting customer_id try like this
    if let data = myJSON["data"] as? [[String: Any]] {
        for jsonDict in data {
            var try = jsonDict["customer_id"] as? String
        } 
    }
}
```

In Swift use Swift native `Dictionary` and `Array` instead of `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` same way as I have used in the answer.

Comment: I tried  "if var myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String : Any]
                    {}", it won't still go inside the if statement

Comment: @ReversedcigoL Also use `if let` instead of `if var` if you are not mutating the value.

Comment: Hey there, it still wont go inside the if statement :( I have putted 'print 1' before executing that if statement, and 'print 2' inside that if, and it wont have no idea why.

Comment: It just prints 'print 1'

Comment: @ReversedcigoL I am not sure but may be you are getting response as string try once `if let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? String { }` and add print statement and check it is printing.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: can you show the output of just this `let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])` now just `print(myJSON)` and check what it is.

Comment: lol i forgot to comment that pretag in my php file @.@ It's now working, thank you so much! Programming in mac is just .... hahaha

Comment: @ReversedcigoL Welcome mate :)